# How to generate a SAS token for a ServiceBus subscription with the python azure sdk?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-sdk-python

I am building a service that needs to create at runtime a servicebus namespace, topic and subscriptions. 
I need to genrate the sas token(or url) to the subscription created by the service and send it to other services in the system.

How can i generate the sas token with the azure python sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd note in addition to Jim's accurate answer:  one can also approach this using the [azure-mgmt-servicebus](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-servicebus/) SDK.  It would require using `azure.common.credentials.ServicePrincpalCredential` for authentication, but would give a slightly more structured flow; not only to [create the namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.namespaces_operations.namespacesoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--namespace-name--parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false--polling-true----operation-config-) and [topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.topics_operations.topicsoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--namespace-name--topic-name--parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-)/[subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.subscriptions_operations.subscriptionsoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--namespace-name--topic-name--subscription-name--parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-), but [to create or update authorization rules against a given topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.topics_operations.topicsoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-authorization-rule-resource-group-name--namespace-name--topic-name--authorization-rule-name--rights--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) or [the namespace itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.namespaces_operations.namespacesoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-authorization-rule-resource-group-name--namespace-name--authorization-rule-name--rights--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-), and then [fetch your keys programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.namespaces_operations.namespacesoperations?view=azure-python#list-keys-resource-group-name--namespace-name--authorization-rule-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-).

See the following as a self-contained example:

```py
from azure.mgmt.servicebus import ServiceBusManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.servicebus.models import AccessRights

client_id = 'REPLACEME'
client_secret = 'REPLACEME'
subscription = 'REPLACEME'
tenant = 'REPLACEME'
resource_group_name = 'REPLACEME'
namespace_name = 'REPLACEME'
authorization_rule_name = 'REPLACEME'
topic_name = 'REPLACEME'
subscription_name = 'REPLACEME'
authorization_rule_rights = [AccessRights.manage]

credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id, client_secret, tenant=tenant)

client = ServiceBusManagementClient(credential, subscription)

client.namespaces.create_or_update(resource_group_name, namespace_name)
client.topics.create_or_update(resource_group_name, namespace_name, topic_name)
client.subscriptions.create_or_update(resource_group_name, namespace_name, topic_name, subscription_name)
client.topics.create_or_update_authorization_rule(resource_group_name, namespace_name, topic_name, authorization_rule_name, authorization_rule_rights)
rule = client.topics.list_keys(resource_group_name, namespace_name, topic_name, authorization_rule_name)
```

As always, full disclosure, I'm one of the folks maintaining the python azure servicebus lib, so don't hesitate to shout if any of this is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate SAS token for service bus with python, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#generate-a-shared-access-signature-token).

For example (I create a sas token for topic)

1. Generate SAS token

```
sb_name='<service bus name>'
topic='<topic name>'
url=urllib.parse.quote_plus("https://{}.servicebus.windows.net/{}".format(sb_name,topic))
sas_value='your sas policy key value'
sas_name='your sas policy'
expiry = str(int(time.time() + 10000))
to_sign =(url + '\n' + expiry).encode('utf-8') 
sas = sas_value.encode('utf-8')
signed_hmac_sha256 = hmac.HMAC(sas, to_sign, hashlib.sha256)
signature = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(signed_hmac_sha256.digest()))
auth_format = 'SharedAccessSignature sig={0}&se={1}&skn={2}&sr={3}'
auth=auth_format.format(signature,expiry,sas_name,url)
print(auth)
```

2. Test

   a. [Send message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue)

   ```
   POST https://<yournamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<topic>/messages
   Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3A%2F%2F<yournamespace>.servicebus.windows.net%2F<yourentity>&sig=<yoursignature from code above>&se=1438205742&skn=KeyName
   ContentType: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8

   <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">This is a message.</string>
   ```

   [image]

   b. Receive message

   ```
   DELETE https://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{topicPath}/subscriptions/{subscriptionName}/messages/head   

   Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3A%2F%2F<yournamespace>.servicebus.windows.net%2F<yourentity>&sig=<yoursignature from code above>&se=1438205742&skn=KeyName
   ```

   [image]